# HTML Form not Working Right

Tags: php, html, forms, sendmail

I built an HTML form and whenever I submit it I'm asked to open up G Mail or Outlook. When I do, a new email is opened with the correct email address. The problem is I want it to send without opening anything. I would like to only use HTML for the form, no PHP/MySQL.

```
        <form method="post" action="mailto:contact@walkerloden.com" enctype="text/plain">
            <p>Name: <input type="text" name="Name" size="20"></p>
            <p>Email: <input type="text" name="Email" size="20"></p>
            <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit"></p>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have your form action set to mailto anything.

You should instead have that direct to a script you've written where you can accept the POST variables and then send an email.  There is a native PHP function called `mail()` which will do just that.  Your code should look like this:

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="scripts/mailtome.php" enctype="text/plain">
    <p>Name: <input type="text" name="Name" size="20"></p>
    <p>Email: <input type="text" name="Email" size="20"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit"></p>
</form>
```

**PHP - mailtome.php**

```
<?php
    $name = stripslashes(trim($_POST['Name']));
    $email = stripslashes(trim($_POST['Email']));
    $to = 'email@address.com'; 
    $subject = 'CONTACT FORM';

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email";

    if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $name.' - '.$email))
        echo("It worked");
    else
        echo("Something went wrong");
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just tried this and it emailed me correctly, but it only emailed me the text 'From:' and 'Email:'. It did not email the text I actually entered into the form.

Comment: Try removing the enctype and seeing if that does anything.  If not, try changing the `$_POST` to `$_REQUEST` or `$_GET`.  Probably won't do anything, but it's worth a try.

Comment: removed the enctype and it's working. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A form action of `mailto` is not really supported - if you expect the form elements to appear in an email with the wanted address, this is not how forms are supposed to work.

You need to have some server side code that you can post your form to and that will do the actual emailing.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this on sample HTML. You must need PHP or something like send mails. HTML doesn't work on that way.

Action mailto only open your default mail application.

Google is your friend, search before ask. The web is fully plenty example about this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to make a signup form, where users enter their name and email, and press submit to email that information to contact@walkerloden.com.  If that is correct, then you have a couple options:

1. Use a mailto link, which is kind of what you are doing here.  Usually these are just hyperlinks and not forms.  This technique will prompt the user to choose an email client for actually sending the email.  This is what is going on when you are asked to open gmail or outlook.  The upside is that it doesn't require a server.  The downside is that the user needs to actually complete the process of sending the email, in the email client.
2. Make a server-side script capable of sending an email.  You can do this in PHP or whatever language you want.  Then make a form that submits to this server-side script.  In this option, the user only has to press submit, but you'll have to set up the server-side script, which you mention that you don't want to do.

If you happen to be running this signup form from within a site like WordPress or some other blogging software, they often have built-in ways to make a signup form to save you the trouble.